# Is it possible to break the execution in gdb at the first assignment of inf?

Tags: c, gdb, nan

Is there a command in `gdb` that I can run to make it automatically stop (break) at the first occurrence of assignment of NaN or inf to a variable, that is when RHS of an executed assignment is NaN or inf (for example when I divide something by zero and try to assign the result to a variable)?

Comment: It is possible with `feenableexcept` call, but it wil break a bit earlier, when your try to divide by zero.

Comment: I can't seem to find an example of code using `feenableexcept` online. Care to briefly explain how one would use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With gcc on Linux you can turn floating-point exceptions to `SIGFPE` signal. You can call `feenableexcept(FE_DIVBYZERO)` to catch all subsequent floating point divisions by zero in your code. If you run this code in gdb it will stop on `SIGFPE` signal. This is default behavior for most other signals as well.
This code was taken and modified from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2949452/72178

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <fenv.h>

int main(void) {
    double x, y, z;
    feenableexcept(FE_DIVBYZERO);

    x = 1;
    y = 0;
    z = x / y;

    return 0;
}
```

gdb will stop on division by zero:

```
$ gdb -q ./a.out
Reading symbols from ./a.out...
(gdb) r
Program received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
0x0000000000401153 in main () at 1.c:10
10      z = x / y;
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 0):

Under many aspects, 
[`NaN`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN)
is a value like any other. Therefore, I don't believe that it is possible to have this generate a special event in every case.

Depending on the architecture you are programming for, there may be a *division-by-zero* event which might be quite easy to catch.
Note however that divisions by zero are not the only way to produce a `NaN` value. (Again depending on the architecture) performing another operation with a `NaN` operant may raise an event/exception (e. g., 
"invalid operation"). 
This may point into some direction to generate a gdb breakpoint by adding some code to the system under debug (if that is an option).

Beside triggers from exception events, conditional watchpoints may be an option:
If you aren't just looking for `NaN` values *anywhere*, a watchpoint on a certain variable, which is limited to a condition can be a good solution.

Under certain circumstances, both ideas won't help you further:
If, for example, the `NaN` appears at some places in a buggy (or unstable) numeric implementation in HPC context, additional numeric operations and conditional breakpoints/watchpoints normally aren't feasible because the overhead will "choke" the calculation before it even generated `NaN` values.

Comment: How would I catch division by zero in gdb (for example, in Linux x64)?

Comment: I've been working mostly with embedded architectures recently, so I'm afraid that I don't have a good suggestion where to find that information. But with Linux/x64 there is likely somebody around who can help you. I'd suggest to add this information to your question.